# access S3 with terraform and bitbucket pipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, bitbucket, terraform-provider-aws

I have a CI/CD pipeline on bitbucket. I want to run some terraform commands. Currently, I get an error in the 3rd "Select workspace" step.

```
image: hashicorp/terraform

pipelines:
  branches:
    test:
      - step:
          name: 'Navigate to Dev'
          script:
            - cd terraform/environments/dev
          condition:
            changesets:
              includePaths:
                - "terraform/modules"
                - "terraform/environments/dev"
      - step:
          name: 'Initialize Terraform'
          script:
            - terraform init
      - step:
          name: 'Select workspace'
          script:
            - terraform workspace select default
```

```
│ Error: Backend initialization required, please run "terraform init"
│ 
│ Reason: Unsetting the previously set backend "s3"
```

even though the `terraform init` command ran successfully in the previous step. This could be because my current pipeline is not able to access S3/AWS.

There is already a provider.tf file in terrafrom/environments/dev

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "eu-central-1"
  assume_role {
    role_arn    = "arn:aws:iam::123:role/terraform-access"
    external_id = "abc"
  }
}

terraform {
  required_version = "> 1.0"

  backend "s3" {
    key         = "dev.tfstate"
    region      = "eu-central-1"
    bucket      = "abc.4flow-vista.com"
    role_arn    = "arn:aws:iam::123:role/terraform-access"
    external_id = "abc"
  }
}
```

but i am not referencing this file anywhere in my bitbucket-pipelines.yml. Do I need to? If so, how and where?

Comment: What policies does `arn:aws:iam::123:role/terraform-access` have assigned?